# Crop screenshot and share?

Tags: ios, swift, uigraphicscontext

I have done the coding for full screenshot without navigation bar but I also don't want the "Motivate me" button.

[image]

Also if anyone know how to share the crop screenshot to Facebook?

Here is the code for screenshot:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size,false,0);
self.view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
var image:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the motivate me button isn't inside the hierarchy of the view that you are taking the screenshot on. Move it onto a separate view and then use the same code that you already have. This will do exactly what you are after.

Or if you want to crop the whole photo you can use the following, please replace the value in heightOfButton to suit:

```
var heightOfButton: CGFloat = 100
var size = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
size.height -= heightOfButton
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size,false,0);
self.view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
var image:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Cant we just write a code and crop a image and saved it to photo library

Comment: @swimnny 89  thanks for your answer.Its great but the width is not coming good so how to change the width

Comment: You can change the width by using size.width = //put value here. Do this on the line after size.height -= heightOfButton and before UIGraphicsBegin...

Comment: No problem, glad i could help.

Comment: can you also help me if i want to share the crop to facebook ? @Swinny89

Answer (score 1):

Just hide the `UIButton` before you take the screenshot and unhide it after you take the screenshot.

```
func screenshot() {
    // Hide button
    myButton.alpha = 0.0

    // Take screenshot
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size,false,0)
    self.view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    var image:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    // Unhide button
    myButton.alpha = 1.0
}
```

To share your image to Facebook you can use a [SLComposeViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/).

On a side note, you don't need to use `;` at the end of each line in Swift.